# Insert multiple rows for a single value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, sql-insert

Here is a mock-up of what I am trying to do:

I have the following table -

Table 1:

```
----------
|ID      |
----------
|    0001|
----------
|    0002|
----------
```

And need to create the following table -

Table 2:

```
-------------------------------------
|ID      |Table1ID|Value1  |Value2  |
-------------------------------------
|   00001|    0001|     abc|     def|
-------------------------------------
|   00002|    0001|     ghi|     jkl|
-------------------------------------
|   00003|    0002|     abc|     def|
-------------------------------------
|   00004|    0002|     ghi|     jkl|
-------------------------------------
```

Where Value1 and Value2 values are scalars.

How do I insert into Table 2 multiple rows that have the same value from Table 1 for all values of Table 1?

Comment: How is the data to be inserted created? Where does 'abc', 'def' etc come from?

Comment: Other columns (ID, Value1, Value2) are coming from?

Comment: @Dale K all the other values are scalar values that I need to create from thin air. They don't exist yet.

Comment: @MohitVaghadiya see above

Comment: @philipxy Thank you for the tip about clarifying. Given the content of the question could you be more specific about what code or details you would have liked me to include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want a `cross join` with a derived table:

```
insert into table2 (table1id, value1, value2)
select t1.id, v.value1, v.value2
from table1 t1
cross join (values ('abc', 'def'), ('ghi', 'jkl')) v(value1, value2)
```

Comment: I understand the cross join and the table value constructor.
Can you explain the "v(value1, value2)" part

Comment: @ChaitanyaChowgule: these are aliases for the derived table that is generated by  `values()`, and its column.

Comment: Got it. Thanks this is exactly what I am looking for.